# Given a fixed position Element, How to show a scrollbar when the item scrolls off the page

Tags: html, css

please take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/T6Hhy/1/

What I have here is a rightcol that is position:fixed. The issue I'm having is that items are scrolling off the page, but the scroll bar is not appear.

How can I have a fixed position column, as I don't want the column to scroll when a user scrolls the page, but have the column have a scrollbar if items are scrolling off the page?

Thanks

Comment: "please take a look at this fiddle"

Comment: fiddle is handy, but I agree the relevant code should also be here on SO for future proofing

Comment: I just thought it sounded funny

Answer (score 1):

use the following css property:

```
overflow:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you can do something like this:

```
#wrapper #rightCol {
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    left: auto;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    width: 245px;
    max-width: 245px;
    background: Red;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y: auto;` for `#wrapper #rightCol` will do the job.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T6Hhy/2/

The user scroll the element which has the cursor above it.